# .getDownloadURL() does not respect image clipping (Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip

I want to download a clipped version of image with `getDownloadURL()`, but the result only maintains the bounds of clip polygon, not the shape itself.

This is [an example script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6dc94f90ac4088a92befe1b2b6e63a42):

```
var no2_coll = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2");

// irregularly shaped polygon
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[36.19717602142744, 36.235397497040246], [35.03262524017744, 34.38876424418324],
[39.17447094330244, 34.37062991132883], [39.41617016205244, 36.36820725445314], [38.17471508392744, 35.3890351383359]]]);

var image = no2_coll.select("tropospheric_NO2_column_number_density")
  .filterBounds(aoi).first();


// this clips an image, but has no effect on result of .getDownloadURL()
var img_clip = image.clip(aoi);

// this has effect on result of .getDownloadURL()
var img_clip_double_mask = img_clip.mask(img_clip.mask());

var downloadArgs = {
  name: 'expected_clipped_image',
  crs: image.projection(),
  scale: 7000,
  region: aoi
};

var url = img_clip_double_mask.getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);

print(url);
```

So while both `img_clip` and `img_clip_double_mask` are rendered as a clipped image on `Map`, it is only when you change  `img_clip` to `img_clip_double_mask` (essentially self masking - but seems redundant) when you get clipped image from `.getDownloadURL()`.

Why is that?